# Calculating % increase in the number of tweets my content gets month over month

Tags: twitter

Do you know of a way to calculate the % increase in the number of tweets my content gets month over month?

Answer (score 1):

If by "content" you mean articles you post on your website that get tweeted, you can track hits generated through Twitter by installing Google Analytics on your site & [configuring it to show visits referred](http://www.seomoz.org/blog/segmenting-social-traffic-in-google-analytics) by Twitter.

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like [klout](http://klout.com/) which will give you a general overview..